# Override interface with different signature

Tags: java

I have the following problem:

an Interface with a simple listener, **inerithed from a library**:

```
public interface RequestListener<RESULT> {

    void onRequestFailure(FooException fooException);

    void onRequestSuccess(RESULT result);
}
```

a class who extends FooException:

```
 public class MyCustomFooException extends FooException {
      . . .
    }
}
```

and I need to `overload` the signature of the `onRequestFailure` method with my custom class.

something like this:

```
public interface MyCustomListener<RESULT> extends RequestListener<RESULT> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(MyCustomFooException e);

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(RESULT result);

}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: *"overload" the signature of the override "onRequestFailure"* - What do you mean by that?

Comment: In a word: you can't.  Your code doesn't follow the Java coding conventions.  Are you a .NET developer?

Answer (score 3):

You could use another typed Parameter to your interface :

```
public interface RequestListener<RESULT,T extends FooException> {

    void onRequestFailure(T fooException);

    void onRequestSuccess(RESULT result);
}
```

Then when you implement your interface, you can define :

```
public interface IglooListener<RESULT> extends RequestListener<RESULT,MyCustomFooException> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(MyCustomFooException e);

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(RESULT result);

}
```

Comment: That's what I also wanted to say: it IS possible ;)

Comment: I can't do that because RequestListener is inerithed from a library

Comment: Then you should just use the basic `onRequestFailure(FooException)` and check identify your type with `e instanceof MyCustomFooException`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that (in a class). If you do it, you're no longer implementing the   `RequestListener` interface. You need to use the exact same signature from the
interface: `void onRequestFailure(FooException fooException);`

If you do it in an interface and if you use another signature, you're extending the original interface by just adding a new method to it. If a non-abstract class later on implements the extended `IglooListener` interface, it will have to define both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `@Override` from the method in `IglooListener` interface. you will be good to go. In that case you will be having two methods in `IglooListener` one from the `RequestListener` and other one from the `IglooListener`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Java because your inheriting class would narrow the possible input parameter types to a subset originally allowed and could therefore not behave like the original interfaced intended to.

**EDIT** Just like the other answers state, you can *add* a method with this signature, but it would not override the interface method.